# Accessing Postgres database inside Dokku container from outside

Tags: postgresql, dokku

I'm having a hard time finding a way to access Postgres database inside Dokku's contaner (based on docker) from outside of the machine using pgAdmin. Is there a way to do that? Do I need to use a different client? I'm exposing database using `dokku postgres:expose` command.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To connect with a pgadmin you can get all the necessary information from the DATABASE_URL.

```
➜  ~ dokku postgres:info your-database-db
       DSN: postgres://postgres:bf8f1cb443c35cd1ae0a58617ef348cd@dokku-postgres-your-database-db:5432/your_database_db
```

Because dokku have the same foundation as Heroku you can extract the information to connect with pg database. The important consideration is that dokku generate a random port for exposure your database. You can get a random port or set any that you want.

```
[database type]://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[database name]
```

Exposing the database and getting the real port:

```
➜  ~ dokku postgres:expose your-database-db
 !     Service is already started
-----> Service your-database-db exposed on port(s) 17825
```

Now in your pg admin you will add the next information and hopefully connect without issues.

```
username: postgres
password: bf8f1cb443c35cd1ae0a58617ef348cd
hostname: Your-Dokku-Host-URL (Ex. example.com or IP of your dokku server)
port: 17825
```

Also, if you are running dokku in AWS EC2, for example, you need to allow access to this port on the instance, adding a *Custom TCP Rule* in the *Inbound* section of the *Security Group* this instance is associated with.

Comment: In testing this command, I noticed you may need to specify the port you'd like to expose (running dokku version 0.19.6):
`dokku postgres:expose your-database-db PORT`

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible using ssh tunnel.

`dokku postgres:list` for all postgres instances

`dokku postgres:info DBNAME` checks exposed ports (if it has) and credentials

- Use `DNS` for credentials, as mentioned in previous answer
- `Exposed ports` - check whether app looks to the internet
- `Internal IP` - host ip, that can be used over ssh

In your postgres client choose an option with ssh tunnel or forward port using putty or etc.